# Style data trigger to color row on datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatrigger

I have code:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="MediaNet.View.MusicWindow.MusicWindow"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                 xmlns:musicVM="clr-namespace:MediaNet.ViewModel.MusicWindowViewModel"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
                 mc:Ignorable="d"
                 d:DesignHeight="350" d:DesignWidth="557">
        <UserControl.DataContext>
            <musicVM:MusicWindowViewModel />
        </UserControl.DataContext>
        <UserControl.Resources>
            <musicVM:TimeSpanConverter x:Key="TimeSpanConverter" />
            <musicVM:CurrentSongIndexConverter x:Key="CurrentSongIndexConverter" />
        </UserControl.Resources>
             <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MusicItems}" SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex}" >
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CurrentSongIndex, Converter={StaticResource CurrentSongIndexConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"  Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background"  Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu >
                <MenuItem Command="Delete">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image  />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Song options">
                    <MenuItem Header="Play to this song" Command="{Binding SetStopPositionCommand}"  />
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid>
```

MusicItem   is

```
ObservableCollection<Song>
```

view model:

```
namespace MediaNet.ViewModel.MusicWindowViewModel
{
    public class MusicWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
    {
 #region CurrentSongIndex
        private int _currentSongIndex;
        public int CurrentSongIndex
        {
            get { return _currentSongIndex; }
            set
            {
                _currentSongIndex = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentSongIndex"));
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
 }
}
```

Converter:

```
namespace MediaNet.ViewModel.MusicWindowViewModel
{
    class CurrentSongIndexConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int CurrentSongIndex = (int)value;
            return CurrentSongIndex > 0;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

This should set background color to  row in data grid, but now work.
Haw can I tell trigger to which row should it change background ?

Answer (score 1):

The `Style` will be applied to every row in the `DataGrid`. The `Binding` in the `DataTrigger` should be relative to the `DataContext` of each row. This ensures that for each row, the binding will be evaluated.

Please clarify/verify the following:

- How exactly does this "not work"? Are no rows being highlighted, all rows being highlighted?
- Does your converter work? Have you verified that it is returning `true` when expected to properly evaluate the trigger binding?

**UPDATE**

Looking at your updated code sample, the problem is that `CurrentSongIndex` is not in the `DataContext` in each `DataGridRow`. Per your XAML, you have `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MusicItems}"`.

When each row of the grid is databound, `DataGridRow.DataContext` is set to the corresponding `Song`. When that happens, the binding no longer has access to the `CurrentSongIndex` because it's part of the `MusicWindowViewModel`.

Try changing your data trigger binding to something like this:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.CurrentSongIndex, Converter={StaticResource CurrentSongIndexConverter}}
```

This will force the binding to look at the `DataContext` of the window who's `DataContext` is the `MusicWindowViewModel` which contains the `CurrentSongIndex` property.

Comment: Is the `CurrentSongIndex` property defined on each item in the `DataGrid`?

Comment: What do you mean? CurrentSongIndex is property in view model which change after song is played. Should this property be part of type bind to datagrid items ?

Comment: But where is it defined? If `CurrentSongIndex` is not in the scope of each `DataGridRow` the binding will fail which will explain why your converter is not being invoked. Can you expand your code sample to include your view model?